# How to write SQL and LINQ to get the one record from a result with where condition?

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have a table Tab1 with millions of records:

```
Tab1(id, id1,id2, value, ...)
```

With SQL like:

```
Select * from Tab1 Where id1=123;
```

I get 100 records. then I want to get one which has maximum of id value from this 100 records.

How to write the simplest SQL for this?

When I use EF to match this table to a Entity in EF, how to write the LINQ to get same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with ORDER BY and TOP.

In SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Tab1
WHERE id1 = 123
ORDER BY id desc
```

In Linq with EF:

```
Tab1.Where(t => t.id1 == 123).OrderByDescending(t => t.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Yes, your solution is better, +1

Comment: Performance is completely negligible if you have an index over the id column. If it's a primary key, this will likely already have been created for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way can be this:

```
Select * from Tab1 Where id1=123 AND id = (SELECT First(Max(id)) from Tab1 where id1 = 123)
```

You can remove the `First` if values are distinct (I don't know how `Max` behaves if there are multiple rows with the same maximum value)

About `Linq` you can use something similar to:

```
Tab1.Where(t => t.id == 123).OrderByDescending(t => t.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you. That's I am trying. First is not available for SQL Server 2008. Maybe only for 2010? I will try your LINQ. Thanks again.

Comment: this is error message from SQL Server 2008 form 'First': 'First' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: You can remove the First clause